# How to predict values of x given values of y (with previous x and y values included)

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R, and I want to predict orbit times of planetary objects based on their average distance from the Sun (in AU).

I thought using R would be great, so I have set

```
x<-c(0.387,0.723,1.000,1.524,5.203,9.537)
y<-c(87.969,224.701,365.256,686.980,4329.630,10751.805)
```

I typed `model=lm(y~x)` to fit a model onto it and then used `predict.lm(model, newdata=new)`, where `new=c(19.191,30.069,39.482).`

I am returned with values but they are really off. I also tried taking the log of all the y values and tried that with the same process I just detailed. However, the values I am returned with are still off. I would appreciate any help to this problem or a resource that provides more help for R in this area. Thanks so much!

*However, the given data value's plot was exponential, so if anyone could help to fit an exponential model instead of linear would be great*.

Answer (score 1):

Your fit is off, because you try to fit a linear model to something that is not linear. Without being an astronomer, I think [Kepler's Third Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler's_laws_of_planetary_motion#Third_law_of_Kepler) is applicable. This formula, taken from Wikipedia, depicts the relationship between orbit times (in days) and distance (AU).

[image: foo+bar]

This could be rewritten as:

[image: foo+bar]

Which can be simplified to

[image: foo+bar]

Taking the log and fitting a linear model would work when the underlying process is exponential.

From [here](https://datascienceplus.com/fitting-polynomial-regression-r/) it seems that your model should be something like, although probably not exact, this: `model=lm(y~x + I(X^(3/2)))`.

Comment: :) Kepler's Third Law was what I was trying to predict! Basically, I wanted to use the first six x and y values to predict the next three y values based off 3 given x values. I am really new, so will your model help me in this endeavour?